# Odoo client error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'form')

Tags: javascript, amazon-ec2, odoo, odoo-13

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'form')

I get this error when I try to open the Settings as an Admin. Since I can't access my Settings page, I am unable to activate the debugger also.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'form')
    at http://65.2.111.189/web/content/3316-e929ab4/web.assets_backend.js:448:309
    at _.each._.forEach (http://65.2.111.189/web/content/1908-99650a5/web.assets_common.js:108:558)
    at Class._generateActionViews (http://65.2.111.189/web/content/3316-e929ab4/web.assets_backend.js:448:229)
    at http://65.2.111.189/web/content/3316-e929ab4/web.assets_backend.js:443:497
```

I had installed a module to take auto-backups of DB to Google Drive, and since I can't access my settings page, even the Google Drive error is popping up whenever I open any page like CRM or Invoice.

```
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 624, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 310, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 14, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 669, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 350, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 339, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 915, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 515, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1342, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1334, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 466, in __getitem__
    return self.registry[model_name]._browse(self, (), ())
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 177, in __getitem__
    return self.models[model_name]
KeyError: 'google.drive.config'
```

Kindly suggest what can be done to resolve this. And to add to my bad luck, I have forgotten the root password to the backend. The service is hosted in AWS EC2.